# Raspberry Pi Contiki rpl-border-router tun0 is down

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, contiki

I followed the instructions of the following project on hackster.io, to make the raspberry pi a 6LoWPAN border router (https://www.hackster.io/leoribg/6lowpan-border-router-297b90).

I successfully compiled the rpl-border-router and flashed my CC2650.

On the Pi side, I built the tunslip6 and when I ran it I got a different output than the example.

More specifically, the process "freezes" at line

```
*** Address:aaaa::1 => aaaa:0000:0000:0000
```

and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, I get a message that tun0 is down.

I have enabled IPv6 and have restarted my Pi.

Any indications / hints are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Update!

I found the solution based on another tutorial (https://sunmaysky.blogspot.bg/2015/11/how-to-buildset-contiki-rpl-border.html).

Firstly, always make sure that you have contiki up-to-date in both the Linux environment and the Raspberry Pi.

```
git clone https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki.git
cd contiki
git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
git pull
```

So, basically the steps are:

1. **Edit contiki files on a Linux environment.**

   ```
   cd /contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router


   vi project-conf.h
   ```

   (as described in https://www.hackster.io/leoribg/6lowpan-border-router-297b90)

   ```
   vi border-router.c
   ```

   (as described in step 1 https://sunmaysky.blogspot.bg/2015/11/how-to-buildset-contiki-rpl-border.html)
2. **Compile *rpl-border-router* on a Linux environment.**

   ```
   cd contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router

   make TARGET=srf06-cc26xx BOARD=launchpad/cc2650 -j8
   ```
3. **Flash the CC2650 using the .bin file.**
4. **Build tunslip6 on Raspberry Pi.**

   ```
   cd contiki/tools
   make tunslip6
   ```
5. **Connect CC2650 to the Raspberry Pi.**
6. **Run on Raspberry Pi.**

   ```
   sudo ./tunslip6 aaaa::/64 -s /dev/ttyACM0
   ```
7. The process will freeze as mentioned in the 1st post. Simply **reset your CC2650** and it will continue, you will see the IPV6 address.